# Declaring and filling an array in Python from fetching MySql array

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, datetime, numpy-ndarray

Whenever I print out, for example, a table "time" which was in datetime data type in MySql, using python I see this:

```
((datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 23, 39, 38),), (datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 23, 40, 39),), (datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 23, 41, 39),), (datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 23, 42, 40),), (datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 23, 43, 40),), (datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 23, 43, 40),))
```

But in the MySql databases, the variables are defined like this:

```
| 2016-05-18 14:11:06 |
| 2016-05-18 14:12:04 |
| 2016-05-18 14:13:05 |
| 2016-05-18 14:14:04 |
| 2016-05-18 14:15:07 | ...
```

What I want is to declare an array and fill the time in datetime format.

For a float type variable, normally I do this

`var1  = array('f',[0])`

But how I can declare  the "time" variable in datetime data type in python and fill it?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _declare an array and fill the time in datetime format_? I had never heard of the `array` library.

Comment: If you see the the variable  i showed for float type 'var1  = array('f',[0])',  how would you do this for datetime data type?

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you explain what that code is doing? It would also help if you could like all the code and data relevant to this question. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Numpy has a [`datetime64`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) data type - in your example we could do the following:

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 2, 23, 39, 38)
>>> np.array([a], dtype='datetime64[s]')
array(['2015-05-02T23:39:38'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```